# OpenGraph: The webpage preview Title and Image for Reddit posts fails

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, facebook-opengraph

Test link is here: https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/14h90hk/what_browser_do_you_use/

1. iMessages, WhatsApp, Twitter render preview of this Test link with correct `og:title` and `og:image`.
2. Other online link preview tests would not render it. Also, the library that I use also does not render it correctly.

   - https://www.opengraph.xyz/
   - https://link-previews.stephanbogner.de/
   - https://socialsharepreview.com/
3. A library that I have been using also fails for Reddit posts.

When I saw the page source, the `og:title` and `og:image` are in `<HEAD>` section only. Can someone please tell me why is it failing?

Please help.

Comment: I don't think OpenGraph parameters has got anything to do with the API restrictions. Also, other apps are able to render.